# SSIS File exist check without script task

Tags: ssis

Is there any way to check if file exist without script task? May be foreach loop container or something else..

Comment: Why do you not want to use the script task?

Comment: 64 bit issue.I get error for PreCompiledBinarycode and the hotfix installation is not an option as client resufsed to install it. So I have to think of some alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to check for Files without using a Script Task.

```
1) Add a ForEach Loop Container to your Control Flow.
2) On ForEach Collection pane, set Enumerator to "Foreach File Enumerator"
3) Set Folder to your Source Folder.
4) Set Files to your File Spec (*.*).
5) On Variable Mappings, create new variable "User::FileExistsFileName"
6) You then just need to configure two output Lines for the ForEach Loop:

7) For Success Line:  Double-click the Connector Line, set:

Evaluation operation:  Expression
Value:  Success
Expression:  @[User::FileExistsFileName] != ""

8) For Failure Line, set:

Evaluation operation:  Expression or Constraint
Value:  Failure
Expression:  @[User::FileExistsFileName] == ""
```

I like to set the Evaluation operation for Failure to "Expression or Constraint" simply to turn the line Red.

Comment: Are you suggesting basically creating an "empty" ForEachLoopContainer, and then using that to set a variable to determine flow? I wasn't able to get that to work. :( It seems like the ForEachLoopContainer needs to have something inside it. No?

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with using a custom component, try this one: [File Properties Task](http://filepropertiestask.codeplex.com/).  It's open source, so you can see exactly what it's doing.  You need to install it on your dev and prod boxes - with the installer or manually into the GAC.  But do that, and you have a drag and drop task easier to use than the File System Task... but then, I'm biased...

Comment: I am helpless I can't install anything from open source on client;s servers.

Comment: You want closed-source instead?  Try Pragmatic Works.  They have a toolbox that has a similar Task in it.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for the same thing and thought I would share the solution I finally came up with, just in case anyone is still interessted:

I just used an execute process task to run a simple "IF NOT EXIST" command, handling the exit codes in the package.

Relevant task configuration:

`Executable:` C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
`FailTaskIfReturnCodeIsNotSuccessValue:` True
`Expressions > Arguments:` "/C IF NOT EXIST \"" + @[User::PATH_TO_FILE] + "\" ( EXIT 1 ) else ( EXIT 0 )"
`WindowStyle:` Hidden
`MaximumErrorCount:` a number equally or higher than the number it is potentially failing (e.g. when checking files existence in a loop)

Add an `OnError EventHandler` to the Execute Process Task and set system variable `Propagate` to `False` to stop it bubbling up the failure(s) to the parent container.
If you don't want to bother about the `MaximumErrorCount` and failing tasks you could simply "ECHO" the result and pass the StdOut to a variable you can then check inside an expression.